# How do I call bootstrap modal and at the same time pass parameter to a component inside the modal?

Tags: vue.js

I have a list of result (which already works). How do I call the bootstrap modal and at the same time pass parameter to a component inside the modal? I have tested the modal and the bootstrap modal can be called manually.

```
<template>
  <div class="main">
          <ol>
            <li
              v-bind:key="searchResult.id"
              v-for="searchResult in searchResults"
              @click="?(searchResult.snippet.resourceId.videoId)"
            >
              {{ searchResult.snippet.title }}
            </li>
          </ol>
          <b-modal id="modal-1" title="BootstrapVue" :hide-footer="true">
            <p class="my-4"><VideoIFrame /></p>
          </b-modal>
        </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import VideoIFrame from "@/components/VideoIFrame.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    VideoIFrame
  },
  data() {
    return {
      searchResults: []
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Some code reduced for brevity

This is the code for the component

```
<template>
  <div class="videoWrapper">
    <iframe
      :src="iframesrc"
      frameborder="0"
      allow="autoplay; encrypted-media"
      allowfullscreen
    ></iframe>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { bus } from "../main";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      iframesrc: null
    };
  },
  created() {
    debugger;
    bus.$on("iframesrc", data => {
      debugger;
      this.iframesrc = data;
    });
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Could you also show where you call `$bus.emit('iframesrc', url)` from?

Comment: @tao, I have another VideoPlayList component which I emit it by `bus.$emit("iframesrc", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + videoId);`

Comment: Instead of emitting you want to save the value to a `Vue.observable()` which is imported into both that list and `VideoIFrame.vue`. If you add `VideoPlayList.vue`'s contents into a fork of [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-wright-0vu8x?file=/src/App.vue) I'll show you how to use `Vue.observable()` to share data between components.

Comment: Okay, I have added VideoPlayList.vue. Actually, I have another Playlist.vue view which uses both component VideoPlayList.vue and VideoIFrame.vue. Here, the view is Search.vue which uses only VideoIFrame.vue component.

Comment: Could you also share the link to the fork? I don't have it (since you forked it - you can't edit my sandbox as I couldn't edit one of your sandboxes). When I do, it automatically creates a fork, with a random url. I need the link to your fork to see what you added.

Comment: Okay sure, this is the [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-dubinsky-hijil?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226367/discussion-between-tao-and-steve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I see with what you have is you're binding on `$bus`'s `iframesrc` event inside the `VideoIFrame`'s `created`. But `VideoIFrame` is created only when you open the modal. So if the bus emits `iframesrc` when modal is not open, `iframesrc` will be `undefined` when you open it, because it missed the event when it was emitted.

To solve this problem, you have to place the code catching the emit outside of the modal component.

You could simply place it in the modal's parent and pass it as `prop` to VideoIFrame component, in the template.

Other possible solutions, if you don't want to couple VideoIFrame with modal's parent is to use any state management solution (e.g: Vuex, [Vue.observable()](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-observable)).

Based on your initial example, [here's the update](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-wright-0vu8x?file=/src/components/VideoPlayList.vue), using a simple store (with `Vue.observable()`). In short:

- ditched `$bus` usage
- created a simple store
- imported it in both the list component and and the videoIFrame component and used it to pass the clicked item's id to the videoIFrame.

That's about it.

Answer (score 1):

Same as you always do, using props.
You can read more about it here https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html

I found more issues with your code so lets fix it.

We need to send the component (videoIframe) prop with the desired URL

```
 <template>
  <div class="main">
          <ol>
            <li
              v-bind:key="searchResult.id"
              v-for="searchResult in searchResults"
              @click="showModal(`https://example.com/${searchResult.snippet.resourceId.videoId}`)"
            >
              {{ searchResult.snippet.title }}
            </li>
          </ol>
          <b-modal id="modal-1" title="BootstrapVue" v-model="modalOpen" :hide-footer="true">
            <p class="my-4"><VideoIFrame :framesrc="currentURL " /></p>
          </b-modal>
        </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import VideoIFrame from "@/components/VideoIFrame.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    VideoIFrame
  },
  data() {
    return {
      modalOpen: false,
      currentURL: '',
      searchResults: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
     showModal(videoURI){
         this.showModal = true;
         this.currentURL = videoURI;
      }
  }
};
</script>
```

Iframe component - should declare that it receives a prop by the name "iframesrc" and not in the data object

```
<template>
  <div class="videoWrapper">
    <iframe
      :src="iframesrc"
      frameborder="0"
      allow="autoplay; encrypted-media"
      allowfullscreen
    ></iframe>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { bus } from "../main";

export default {
  props: ['iframesrc']
};
</script>
```

Comment: I also have another VideoPlayList component which I emit it by `bus.$emit("iframesrc", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + videoId);`

Comment: I can call the modal now with your code. But the modal still could not get the `iframesrc` value. Your `:framesrc="currentURL"` suppose to be `:iframesrc="currentURL "`?